# Rails AJAX request not processing as JS but */*

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

My ajax request works, but I do not understand the server logs.  When I look at the server logs it says the following for the ajax request:

```
Processing by UsersController#change_food as */*
```

I do not know why it is saying `*/*`.  I would expect it to say `JS` like so:

```
Processing by UsersController#change_food as JS
```

Here is the entire flow of things. For this ajax request: I simply binded an event listener for when a select box changes, and then I submit an ajax request when the selection changes.  Here is that form field:

```
# _form.html.erb
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :food_type_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select :food_type_id, FoodType.all, :id, :name, {}, {data: {action: 'food_sel', food_change_js_url: "#{user_food_change_js_path}"}} %>        
</div>
```

And here is the actual ajax request:

```
# application.js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  $('[data-action="food_sel"]').on('change', function(){
    var url = $(this).data('food-change-js-url');

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      datatype: "application/js",
      data: {food_type_id: $(this).val()}
    })

  });

});
```

Here is the relevant route:

```
# routes.rb 
get 'user_food_change_js', to: 'users#change_food'
```

Which routes the ajax request to this controller:

```
# users_controller.rb
def change_food
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Which renders this view:

```
# change_food.js.erb
alert("hello world");
```

I originally hoped that I could just put `remote: true` on the select box, and that then whenever the selection changes it would shoot an ajax request up to the server.  Unfortunately `remote: true` only works for a couple things: like for your `form_for`, your `form_tag`, your links, and your buttons.  I couldn't think of a cleaner why of sending an ajax request (via js) to the server when an event is triggered.

**Question**: I feel like I am doing something unconventional since the server log does not say it is processing by `JS` but instead `*/*`.  Is there a more conventional way to do this? One that will say it is processing by `JS`?

---

**Update**

Based on accepted answer: all I had to do was camelCase the `dataType` key and set it properly.  Everything else staying the same: it got it working:

```
# application.js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  $('[data-action="food_sel"]').on('change', function(){
    var url = $(this).data('food-change-js-url');

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "script",
      data: {food_type_id: $(this).val()}
    })

  });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that keys in Javascript objects are case-sensitive, so `datatype` is not the same thing as `dataType`.

Second, the `dataType` key is not the same as `contentType`, although if you leave off `contentType` jQuery will infer it from `dataType`. In your case you want `script`, not `application/js` (as @Ruslan also pointed out).

Putting those together, you want:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "script",
  data: {food_type_id: $(this).val()}
})
```

If that still doesn't work, I would look for places where you are globally setting `contentType`, e.g. by calling `$.ajaxSetup`.

Comment: For Rails 5.2 with rails-ujs only `dataType` is working. Setting `contentType` is not working

Answer (score 3):

try:

`dataType: 'script'`

that might work

Answer (score 2):

Try appending `.js` to your `user_food_change_js_path`.

Also - is `change_food_js.erb` a typo? I would have expected `change_food.js.erb` (dot instead of underscore)

Comment: Yes that was a typo, I will update my question. Thanks!  Your solution was the only one that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
contentType: "text/javascript"
```

Comment: Same thing: the logs still say: `Processing by UsersController#change_food as */*`.  As before: it still works, it just says `*/*` instead of `JS`.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the headers?

`headers: {Accept: '*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript'}`